# What is the difference between createWithoutData and put in Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

The parse android documentation states this:

> Objects can have relationships with other objects. To model this behavior, any ParseObject can be used as a value in other ParseObjects. Internally, the Parse framework will store the referred-to object in just one place, to maintain consistency.

What I understand by this is when I do this for **put** :

```
firstObject =new ParseObject("A");
secondObject= new ParseObject("B");
secondObject.put("A",firstObject);
```

According to the last line of the blockquote, this means that the object is not created in B, it simply stores a pointer in B (for A)

Now this **createwithoutdata**:

> You can also link objects using just their objectIds like so:

```
// Add a relation between the Post with objectId "1zEcyElZ80" and the comment
myComment.put("parent", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Post", "1zEcyElZ80"));
```

This also means that a pointer is used in place of the object, right?

What is the difference between put and createwithoutdata and what are the usecases where you use each one?

**EDIT:**

```
ParseObject parseObject=new ParseObject("TestClass");
    ParseObject parseObject1=new ParseObject("TestObject");
    parseObject.put("ps1",ParseObject.createWithoutData("TestObject",parseObject1.getObjectId()));
    parseObject.saveEventually();
```

In this each time a new instance is getting created...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not asking the right question, actually.  The difference between `put` and `createWithoutData` is that they're completely different methods with totally unrelated purposes.  In both cases you described, you're using the same `put` method.  The difference is in how you're creating the `ParseObject` to put.  In your first example, I believe when you write that to the database, it will insert the B row, then insert the A row with a pointer to the B.  In the second example, you are using the ID from a Post row that is already in the database, and writing a pointer to that row into the Comment row.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand it yet. I am sure they must be used for different purposes but then even in what you said we are just using pointers again, right?  BTW I edited the first code, it seems I made a mistake earlier

Comment: Yes, you're just using pointers again.  The difference is in whether you're using a pointer to a new row, or an existing one.

Comment: I think I sort of got you... I just used this example code to test it....  (See edit) In that case, new instance is getting created (I used put earlier as my first code fragment and the results are same) , although I do get your point that if at all I use queries, I can get the id and then use this createWithoutData and achieve the pointing.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I think you've got it.